# Can I deploy a Web server and an App server to the same AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, amazon-web-services

I have a Rails API and a Node app. Can I deploy both to the same AWS EC2 instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Your EC2 instance just needs to have the appropriate prerequisites installed and enough system resources available to run both.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, this is fine. It is recommended to separate your db behind a firewall though (could be VPC or a security group)